# Cambiar de página con el touchpad de un dispositivo móvil

Tags: php, javascript, css, web

Estoy trabajando en una app web que tiene un menú con varias páginas, la app está echa en mobile-first, y me gustaría que cuando un usuario desliza su dedo hacia la izquierda por la pantalla de un dispositivo movil o tablet cambie de página (a ser posible con un efecto de desplazamiento)

El menú:
[image: menu]

He buscado en internet pero no encuentro nada en claro (puede ser por que no se casi nada de javascript)

Comment: Deberías dejar ejemplos de lo que hayas intentado, tal como tienes la pregunta estás pidiendo que te lo hagan entero. Intenta empezar el código y mostrar tus avances, así también aprenderás más que si alguien te lo da hecho :)